# Recording audio from microphone and headphones

Tags: audio

Using Ubuntu 16.04.

Is it possible to record into a single audio file the incoming and outgoing signals (headphone and mic) of a wireless headset? With which program and instructions?

I have found some resources concerning **ffmpeg** in Windows, using the [DirectShow tool](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow), which is not recognized in my **ffmpeg version 2.8.17-0ubuntu0.1**. So I seem to trip at the first step.

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it mixed, or on different tracks? As far as I know, `ffmpeg` can use multiple sources, or you can set up e.g. a Pulseaudio "virtual sink" that either mixes those signals, or provides those on different channels. Outgoing signals are available through the associated `.monitor` source.

Comment: @dirkt Primarily mixed, although different tracks open to creative solutions. The problem is how to make ffmpeg, or the like, work to that effect. Keywords are appreciated. However, the ideal answer should contains an explanation of the procedure or links thereto. Thanks for considering this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it mixed, and if you don't want to fiddle with `ffmpeg`, make a "virtual" Pulseaudio sink, and two loopback connections, one from the associated `.monitor` source of your headphone sink, and one from the mic.

Follow instructions from e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358164/193028) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/395417/193028).

You can then record with `ffmpeg` (or any other program) from the associated `.monitor` source of your newly created "virtual" sink.